# How to show hidden column in model? laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a model `Driver`.

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'token', 'user_id'];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'token';
    }
}
```

I don't understand when I use `tinker` it returns all the column.

```
$d = \App\Driver::first();
```

But when I try it to method from my controller it doesn't returned all column including the `id` which is very important for relationship. I even tried `return $driver->makeVisible(['id'])` still unsuccessful.

```
public function show(Driver $driver)
{
    return $driver;
}
```

Someone knows what went wrong? Need your help Sirs.

---

**EDITED**: Excuse of my misunderstanding. **It doesn't returned all the column**, It were all `appends` returned I misunderstood/thought it was a column. But I'm confused why it doesn't `404` when its not found in my db.

My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/drivers/{vehicle}', 'DriverController@show');
```

Comment: all column ? can you remove id in your guarded ?

Comment: you get all other fields except `id` in your response or empty response or what?

Comment: how do you call the show method ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 edited my post Sir. sorry I misunderstood the problem

Comment: then you are passing Id in your show method right ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 no I'm passing the `token`, token is actually encrypted strings.

Comment: then you have a column token also in your table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Driver` model looks like this, it should return all fields. But I believe you didn't show us full model, that's why you should verify whether you don't have `toArray` method defined in this model that might choose only some columns to be returned.

It's also possible that you use route model binding in not valid way, so `$driver` here is not existing object so it does not have id set at all - to confirm this you should change:

```
return $driver;
```

into

```
return \App\Driver::first();
```

to see if it changes returned result and now you get model id.

If you have route like this:

```
Route::get('/drivers/{vehicle}', 'DriverController@show');
```

so parameter name is completely different than the one in controller, then Laravel will just inject into controller new object instance, so in your controller `$driver` is in fact same as you used:

```
$driver = new Driver();
```

That's why you should either update parameter name in route or update parameter name in your controller.

Comment: @charles show your route for `show` method

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

**Customizing The Key Name**

If you would like model binding to use a database column other than id when retrieving a given model class, you may override the getRouteKeyName method on the Eloquent model:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'token'; // make sure you have also a token column in your table
}
```

Comment: I made a typo Sir on my `route` paramter. now its working. Thanks for the time Sir.